# Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \sqrt{e^x+e^{-x}+2} dx$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{e^x+e^{-x}+2} \,dx$$

The first intuition for me is to transform $e^x+e^{-x}$ into $2\cosh x$.

Then the integral becomes $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{2\cosh x+2} \,dx=\sqrt{2}\int_0^1 \sqrt{\cosh x+1} \,dx$$ which is still hard to evaluate.

I wonder if there's any possible way to do this integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the identity
$$\cosh(x)+1=2\cosh\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2$$
or not (explicitly) use hyperbolic trig functions and just note that 
$$e^x+e^{-x}+2=\left(e^{\frac{x}{2}}+e^{-\frac{x}{2}}\right)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$e^{x}+e^{-x}+2=\left(e^{x/2}\right)^2+\left(e^{-x/2}\right)^2+2\cdot e^{x/2}\cdot e^{-x/2}=\left(e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}\right)^2$

So, $\displaystyle\int\limits_0^1\sqrt{e^{x}+e^{-x}+2}\ dx
=\int\limits_0^1\left(e^{x/2}+e^{-x/2}\right)\ dx
=2\left[e^{x/2}-e^{-x/2}\right]_0^1
=2\left(e^{1/2}-e^{-1/2}\right)$